# EKS ARM Node stuck in NotReady status - runtime network not ready cni config uninitialized

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS Cluster (AWS) named **cluster-main** running on

- **Kubernetes version:** 1.16
- **Platform version:** eks.4
- **CNI version** v1.6.1

There are two node groups in the cluster

| Cluster Name | Instance Type | AMI Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| generic-node-group | t3a.medium | AL2_x86_64 |
| memory-node-group | r5a.large | AL2_x86_64 |

The nodes in these groups work fine.

I am trying to add a new node group that consists of ARM instances

| Cluster Name | Instance Type | AMI Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cpu-node-group | c6g.xlarge | AL2_ARM_64 |

However, the nodes of this group are stuck in `Not Ready` status and the node group fails to get created due to the issue below

`Conditions:`

| Type | Status | LastHeartbeatTime | LastTransitionTime | Reason | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ready | False | Mon, 31 May 2021 08:40:22 -0400 | Mon, 31 May 2021 08:38:21 -0400 | KubeletNotReady | runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized |

- All node groups have **Node IAM Role ARN**
- All node groups are AWS-managed groups.
- All node groups are deployed under two specific subnets (private)

When I SSH into the EC2 instance I get the following logs under `/var/log/message`

```
1430 cni.go:237] Unable to update cni config: no networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
1430 kubelet.go:2193] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

I've confirmed that the `/etc/cni/net.d` directory is indeed empty

I have another EKS cluster with similar characteristics where the ARM node group is initialized without any issue.
However, I have found two differences. The test cluster uses:

- **Platform version:** eks.5
- **CNI version**  1.7.5

  - amazon-k8s-cni-init:v1.7.5-eksbuild.1
  - amazon-k8s-cni:v1.7.5-eksbuild.1

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a lot of people encountered this issue. Can you try solution described [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/284#issuecomment-601987503)?

Comment: Hi @thomas thanks for the reply.
It seems that the add-ons were indeed never updated. For context, the cluster was initially created at 1.14 version and was later upgraded to 1.16.
I went ahead and upgraded the listed addons but the issue remains. One thing I noticed was that the CNI version remained at v1.6.1. 
The other cluster that I have in place - which was initialized much later but with the same kubernetes version (1.16) uses CNI v1.7.5. 
Any thoughts? Any chance I missed something?

Comment: Hi @thomas it looks like the issue was related to where you pointed me at. Looks like the cluster was never properly upgraded. I had to follow some additional steps  - more specifically manually upgrading the CNI addon to 1.7 and then modifying the `kube-proxy` daemon set configuration to support the `arm64` architecture.
Thank you very much for your help. Very much apprciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - as @thomas suggested the issue was related to the EKS addons.

For context and as I said in my comment, the cluster was initially created at 1.14 version and was later upgraded to 1.16.

However, the `aws-node`, `kube-proxy`, and `coredns` add-ons were never upgraded.
Followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/284#issuecomment-601987503) but the issue remained.

What I did notice though was that the `aws-node` was still using the same CNI image (v1.6.3)

```
kubectl describe daemonset aws-node --namespace kube-system | grep Image | cut -d "/" -f 2
```

After further investigation I had to manually upgrade the CNI version following the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-vpc-cni.html#updating-vpc-cni-add-on)

Lastly, I noticed that an `aws-node` pod was created for my `arm64` node - which previously it didn't.
However, the liveness probe for the pod was failing and the node was still stuck in `NotReady` status.
So I had to edit the configuration for the `kube-proxy` daemon set as described in step (3) of [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-kube-proxy.html#updating-kube-proxy-add-on) guide.